# how to make the report show both of income and expense sql command together at the same time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've 2 sql queries one for income report and the other is for expense report. they work great when they run individually. However I have to create yearly report that show both of  income and expense together with google graph. It turn out that my graph wont' be able to display it correctly because of some non-value of some months. So now I'm trying to join each of them together by using SQL but this seem beyond my knowledge. UNION can't be use in this case. So could you please help me… Thank you.

my sql income is

```
select sum(tbt.bill_total) as bill_total ,iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0,
       sum_vat_total) as vat_total, iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0,  
       sum_vat_total) + sum(bill_total) as sum_of_all, 
       month(showndate) as [month] 
from tbl_bill_total tbt left join 
   (select sum(vat_total) as sum_vat_total , month(showndate) as [month] 
    from tbl_vat_bill_total 
    where if_paid = true and year([showndate]) =" & current_year & "     
    group by month(showndate)) tvt on tvt.month = month(tbt.showndate)        
      where year([showndate]) =" & current_year & " 
      group by  month(showndate) , sum_vat_total
```

and my expense sql is

```
SELECT Sum(tbl_expense.exp_amt) AS SumOfexp_amt, 
       Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS yr, 
       Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS mth 
 FROM tbl_expense 
 GROUP BY Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]), 
             Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) 
 HAVING (((Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]))=" & current_year & "));
```

my table is 
tbl_bill_total

```
bill_id   | bill_total| bill_discount | shown date | if_paid | cust_id | 
   1      |    1000   |    0          |   2/2/15   |   true  |   01
   2      |    1000   |   0           |   15/2/15  |   true  |   02
   3      |     2000  |    0          |   25/2/15  |   false |    03
   4      |    3000   |   0           |   15/3/15  |   true  |   02
   5      |    500    |   0           |   5/4/15   |   true  |   02
   6      |    500    |   0           |   10/4/15  |   true  |   03



tbl_vat_bill_total
vat_id | vat_total | cust_id | if_paid  | showndate | 
    1  |   1000    |   04    |   true   |    5/2/15  
    2  |    2000   |   02    |    true  |   14/3/15



tbl_expense 
exp_id | sup_id   | if_billed   | shown date   | exp_amt |
    1  |   01     |  true       |   27/2/15    |   1000
    2  |   03     |  true       |   22/4/15    |   100
```

I want to have my report look like below

```
Month |   Year  | Bill Total | Vat Total | Sum_of_all     | Expense 
  2   |   2015  |  2000      | 1000      |  3000          |   1000
  3   |   2015  |  3000      | 2000      |  5000          |     0
  4   |  2015   |  1000      |  0        |  1000          |    100
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that i have a clear understanding of your queries but take a note that Union just cares for equal amount of fields with same names...
So a quick and dirty solution would be to modify your queries to have the "same" fields (just use appropriate names) for start and join them...(for expenses in order to be clear, you could set them to be negatives e.g Amount:Expenses * -1)..
If you want something more then a small sample of you data would be most helpfull